# How to disable Wi-Fi temporarily with timeout on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

Is there an app or something to disable Wi-Fi on iOS but automatically re-enable it after a specified time?

Comment: @user It's preferable not to include ‘How to’ at the beginning of a question title as its superfluous to the essence of what's being asked, similar to greetings and valedictions.

Comment: @grgarside, In changing the Title to a question, just adding a "?" would not have made it grammatically correct... hence the "How to" and to be frank I disagree with it being superfluous nor is it IMO in the same vein as greetings and valedictions, however you certainly can reverse my edit if you so choose.

Comment: @user The title doesn't have to be a question—it's fine to leave it as a statement. It's nothing major to rollback—just wanted to let you know. [Some related reading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) (a bit outdated but still relevant)

Comment: @grgarside, Ironically the Title of the link you provided starts off with "How" and the accepted answer shows "How to ..." as one of its good examples while also most of the good examples are in the form of a question. Additionally under "1. Make the topic stand out." ... "Make it easy for them to notice your question." so I take that to be the Title being in the form of a question is not only acceptable but preferable.  I see absolutely nothing wrong with the edit I made and frankly have better things I can go do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as iOS apps are not able to control system hardware such as Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/1151310/timedaccess_ipad_iphone.html) or [this](http://9to5mac.com/2013/10/06/how-to-set-time-limits-on-your-wi-fi-network-using-airport-utility/) can help you... is all i've found about to make a "timer" for iPhone's wifi.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked pages change.